# Is a user's email address confirmed in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, openid

I get email of users by Facebook Graph API, but how can I verify that the user has confirmed his email after registration on Facebook?

Comment: AFAIK a user can not add just any email address to their FB account without “verifying” it by clicking a link in a message sent to that email address. And commonly on the web that’s as verified as it gets with email addresses.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I tested this scenario by creating a new Facebook account and attempting to connect it to sites without verifying my e-mail address. The Facebook dialog did not allow me to do so, explaining that I must first verify my e-mail address before connecting.

Thus, you can rely on e-mails retrieved from Facebook to be "verified" sans policy changes.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to tell if the email is verified, but if the `/me` call on the API returns `verified = true` it means the user has verified their account in some way (credit card, mobile etc). So it's safe to assume the user's account and email are valid.

Comment: Bob wants to access Alice's stackoverflow account. Bob creates a fake facebook account using Alice's email address. He verifies the facebook account using his mobile number. Bob signs into stackoverflow using facebook connect. Stackoverflow sees Alice's email address in the profile information facebook sends back and prompts Bob "we found your account via your email address. Would you like to link to this account?" Bob is now able to sign into Alice's stackoverflow account.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280535/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-email-is-confirmed-on-facebook : The email address you get from Facebook using the Graph API or a FQL query is a verified email. If an account hasn't verified it's email yet it's not possible to get it.